# Replacing Different Strings to One String In Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a math text file called Math-List. In  Math-List, I want to to replace all strings in the forms of

"^ 2 *" , "^ 3 *" , "^ 4 *" ,..., "^ 100 *"

to the string ",".

Is there a systematic method in the Notepad++ to do it.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Check the [regular expression](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions) documentation

Comment: Can you elaborate? Do you want to replace the values inside the double quotes or any pattern "^ # *", ? If that's the case you can do this with find/replace with regular expression

Comment: @raphie as you mentioned in the pattern ^ # * where by #, I mean an integer number.

Comment: In that case @ggorlen answer will suffice, but you can reduce the pattern with just (\^ \d{1,3} \*)

Comment: @raphie that includes 101-999, which OP didn't include in their range. Also, your version omits the `\*` and is read as "0 or more spaces".

Comment: @ggorlen Based on the question, there is a -..., which can means anything, the person implies a pattern where numbers can be 1 to 3 digits. And I didn't omitted the last slash, I forgot to escape the slash, the app translate it as a comment, will fix it, thanks for noticing.

Comment: Not to my understanding, "..." in math means "follow the pattern". "1, 2 ... 10" means "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis#In_mathematical_notation

Comment: Cannot edit my second comment but as @ggorlen mentioned there is a missing slash, the pattern should be (\^ \d{1,3} \\*) if the pattern should find digits up to 3 digits long.

Comment: If that's the case so the list finish on 100 which is 3 digits long, @ggorlen hey sorry if hurt your feelings, I'm tryng to help a person with a question not to compete who has the best answer, I was just adding to your accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks to users that have been contributed in this post.

Comment: Why  down vote? please tell its reason. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex should work (make sure you check "Search Mode: regular expression" in the Replace screen (CTRL+f):

Find what: `\^ (100|\d{1,2}) \*`

Replace with: `,`

#### Explanation

`\^` matches literal `^` (caret) character

matches literal space character

`(100|\d{1,2})` uses alternation to match either literal `100` or 1-2 digits

matches literal space character

`\*` matches literal `*` (asterisk) character

Comment: Thanks a million, especially for your explanation. I am a math student and really need to these explanations.

Comment: Is it possible to ask you to help me about this question: I have a text file that firstly I want to replace "\^\d{1,2}\+c" with "," then replace "
"\^\d{1,2}\*" with "," then "\+c" with ","then replace "\*" with "," and after that I want to replace "\(|\)" with empty( remove "(" and ")"). I mean do this action in order. Is there a way in regex that can be used to do these actions with one command.  I appreciate you for addressing this command. Thanks

Comment: Can you post a new question so I can understand what you're asking clearly? There's not enough room here to come up with a reasonable response.

Comment: If you let me, I edit my question. I don't know why two users downvoted my question.  Because of this, instead of post of a new question, I will edit this question. Thanks

Comment: It's better to post a new one. The reason you got downvoted is probably because you didn't attempt to solve your question yourself. Editing a post to add another question that potentially doesn't have much to do with the answers given is a sure fire way to get more downvotes, not more help. Besides, I don't know the answer to your new question offhand so it won't get much exposure here.

Comment: OK, I post a new question. I appreciate your guidance and support.